# "Parameter Format Not Correct" when typing file paths

Tags: windows-7, command-line, parameters

I've been trying to use the command prompt in Windows 7 to delete a stubborn folder (_MEI50722) from my temp folder. It's a highly-suspect folder in my hunt for some malware I'm thinking is hijacking the old laptop I'm fixing up. But I'm realizing that whenever I type file paths, the command prompt tells me the parameter formats aren't correct. I've been wondering if I've been doing something wrong. Keeping in mind that "Sev" is the user name, Windows clearly shows me the file path is:

```
C:\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722
```

So to delete the folder and its contents, I've been typing:

```
DEL/F/S/Q/A"C:\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722\*"
```

The command prompt returns:

```
Parameter format not correct - ""C:\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722\*""
```

I don't use the command prompt much, so maybe it's obvious, but what on earth am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Spaces missing in your command line. In a maximalist variant:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "C:\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722\*"
:: ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

or at least next code should work (a minimalist variant):

```
DEL /F/S/Q/A "C:\Users\Sev\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI50722\*"
:: ^        ^
```